# How to deal with CoderException: cannot encode a null String with scio

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, spotify-scio

I just started using scio and dataflow. Trying my code to one input file, worked fine. But when I add more files to the input, got the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: cannot encode a null String
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:280)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:621)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:609)
    at com.spotify.scio.util.Functions$$anon$3.processElement(Functions.scala:158)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: cannot encode a null String
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder.getEncodedElementByteSize(StringUtf8Coder.java:136)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder.getEncodedElementByteSize(StringUtf8Coder.java:37)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.registerByteSizeObserver(Coder.java:291)
    at com.spotify.scio.coders.RecordCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(Coder.scala:279)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(WindowedValue.java:564)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.WindowedValue$FullWindowedValueCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(WindowedValue.java:480)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory$ElementByteSizeObservableCoder.registerByteSizeObserver(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:399)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputObjectAndByteCounter.update(OutputObjectAndByteCounter.java:125)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowOutputCounter.update(DataflowOutputCounter.java:64)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:43)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:272)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:621)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:609)
    at com.spotify.scio.util.Functions$$anon$3.processElement(Functions.scala:158)
    at com.spotify.scio.util.Functions$$anon$3$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:240)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:325)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.executeWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:394)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:363)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:291)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:135)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:115)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I guess one of my input files may include some malformed data. But how to bypass the bad data? There is a similar question with Java Beam [com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CoderException: cannot encode a null String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846528/com-google-cloud-dataflow-sdk-coders-coderexception-cannot-encode-a-null-string)
So I tried this:

```
val scText = sc.textFile(input)
scText.setCoder(NullableCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of()))
```

It didn't help. Can someone help me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scio team provided a [solution](https://github.com/spotify/scio/issues/1719) to this problem. Basically add `--nullableCoders=true` in command line argument.